# Use wi-fi as source of internet for TP-Link router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Short question: Is there a way for a router to use an existing Wi-Fi as a source of internet instead of the internet cable from ISP?

Detailed explanation: I share my neighbour's internet connection (due to the excessively high base price per connection charged by the only ISP who services my area). I have my own TP-Link router connected in *Range Extender* mode. Eventually, I realized that his router was getting old and randomly drops the connection sometimes. This causes the repeater (secondary router) to also go down. I understand that I can't access the Internet when his router is down, but I was wondering if there's a possible way to configure my router such that the local connection between all devices connected to the secondary router stays alive even when the primary router goes down?

Comment: You seem to abusing the term *"router"* to mean wireless router.  But what to you mean by *"the **local** connection ... stays alive"*?   That question and the title do not seem to match.

Comment: @sawdust That two devices connected to secondary router can ping each other

Comment: So your title & *"short question"* do not describe the actual problem (and leads to an irrelevant answer).  Configuring your wifi-router in *"Range Extender mode"* is probably the culprit.  Apparently  *"Range Extender mode"* inhibits any local routing, i.e. a WAP mode.

Comment: Which mode should I choose instead?

Comment: Try ping tests between local devices using "Range Extender mode" and then "Wireless Router mode".  Are ping times longer in "Range Extender mode", indicating that packets have to take the extended trip to the primary wireless router?

Comment: @sawdust In both cases, ping ranges from 40 to 100 ms

Comment: A 40ms minimum is poor performance for a WLAN.  Perhaps the test using your wireless router is still with old settings (e.g. SSID, passcode, wifi channel #) that conflict with your neighbor's WLAN?  If you want your own WLAN to operate independent of your neighbor's WLAN, then you have to setup/configure your own wireless network, especially with a different, non-overlapping channel assignment.  Or test only when the neighbor's wifi is off.

Comment: I think that if operated in Range Extender mode, the ping travels from phone A to extender to main router to extender to phone B, causing the extreme ping

Comment: Okay. Then what about *"in both cases, ping ranges from 40 to 100 ms"*?  Assuming that the other case you tested is "Wireless Router mode".

Comment: Oh. My bad. I tested both devs connected to main router vs both connected to extender.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the router. With consumer router in most cases it's not possible since you need to use the WAN port in order to enable routing functions, NAT, etc.

If this is the case, your best solution would be to buy another extender (how do you know it's not your TP-Link router that drops the connection?!) which has an Ethernet port (aka RJ45) that you can connect to your router or to buy a second router.

Comment: I know that the primary router is faulty as the neighbours themselves have told me of the dropping problem existing even before we made this sharing arrangement. Moreover, the secondary router is hardly a month old

Comment: @FitzWatson ok, if it drops other connections as well (even before you were connected), it's a pretty good indication that there's a problem. Still, the answer remains the same. Did you check your router's options yet?

Comment: I'm using TP-Link Archer C20 AC750. What options should I look for in the admin console?

Comment: @FitzWatson as I stated in my question: usually you need to connect the "internet connection" to the WAN port, is there another option for your router? If not you will need a second device

Comment: The router has the ability to connect to wifi as it can connect in Range Extender mode. Can't that ability be "exploited"?

Comment: @FitzWatson If you can run both modi at the same time (extender and router) you can exploit it in part...  if your router puts out the signal it gets over WLAN on the Ethernet LAN ports as well you could try to connect one of the LAN ports to the WAN port. But you will have to turn of your DHCP server, otherwise you have two DHCPs on the same LAN (I assume your neighbour uses a DHCP)

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there's a possible way to configure my router such that the local connection between all devices connected to the secondary router stays alive ( i.e. *"can ping each other"* ) even when the primary router goes down?

Configuring your wireless-router in *"Range Extender mode"* is probably the culprit.
It no longer acts like a WAP to check if local packets can be redirected locally like a switch.
Accessing another local host probably means that the packet has to perform a round-trip back to the primary wireless-router.
Relatively long ping times would confirm this multi-link connection.

You could isolate your local hosts from the primary wireless-router by simply using your wireless-router as a normal wireless-router instead of *"Range Extender mode"*.
Then in order to connect to your neighbor's Internet connection and the primary wireless-router, you would have to acquire another wireless unit, e.g. a WAP.

---

> Short question: Is there a way for a router to use an existing Wi-Fi as a source of internet instead of the internet cable from ISP?

No, the wireless interface is on the LAN side rather than the WAN side of the router services.
If you want to get access to another WLAN while using your wireless-router to provide a local and secured subnet, then one way is to obtain another WAP to connect to the WAN port.

OR
You could try installing alternate firmware on your wireless-router.
No assurances at all, but perhaps an alternate firmware would have a smarter "Range Extender mode" that checked for local traffic instead of blindly forwarding everything.

---

Besides *"Range Extender mode"* and ordinary wireless-router mode, your wireless-router has a third mode, wireless-access-point.
Essentially this is a reduction in features and capabilities, i.e. remove WAN and routing/gateway capabilites, and provides wireless and wired switching.
This mode however will not provide any solution because typically two WAPs cannot access each other (the other WAP being the primary wireless router).
See [Wirelessly Connecting Two Wireless Access Points](http://www.practicallynetworked.com/support/two_ap.htm)

> Generally, (and especially in the case of inexpensive consumer-grade products) APs communicate only with wireless ***clients***.

You cannot operate your wireless-router as a WAP and as a client to the primary wireless router simultaneously.

---

You seem to abusing the term "router" to mean wireless router.  See https://askleo.com/extending-network-wireless-access-point/

Comment: "Generally, (and especially in the case of inexpensive consumer-grade products) APs communicate only with wireless clients." - Is this a hardware limitation or a software one?

Comment: Good question.  I don't have the expertise to give a definitive answer.  I'm inclined to think that it's just software, but maybe there's some HW optimization to isolate some signals.  Or maybe there's added RAM/flash/processor costs that can't be added to price-sensitive gear.

Comment: DD-WRT seems to have a suitable repeater mode. But, sadly, it's not yet available for my router